# Why are some of the links in the Contents page pointing to the wrong page?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{from there}
no text
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{to here}
some text
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{and here}
still more text
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{not here}
or maybe less text
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{also here}
and more text
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{maybe here}
and still more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use `\addcontentsline` here at all? Let `\section` etc. do this job and the links anchors and positions are correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\addcontentsline` does *not* create an anchor, it uses the anchor, that is created before, even if the anchor belongs to one of the previous pages. This is by design, it allows, e.g.:

```
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
```

If `\addcontentsline` would create an anchor, then it would point *below* the section title.

The solution here is to use `\phantomsection`, which creates the needed anchor:

```
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline ...
```